# PHP: Get thousand from number

Tags: php

When the user enters a number from 1000 and above I want to be able to get the thousand for that number in an array.

For example…

Number entered by user: 165124

My array should return:

```
array('thousand_low' => 165000, 'thousand_high' = 165999)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The complete array-returning function, using PHP's native [`floor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) and [`ceil`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) functions:

```
function get_thousands($num) {
  return array(
    'thousand_low'=>floor($num/1000)*1000,
    'thousand_high'=>ceil($num/1000)*1000-1
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$num = 165124;

$result = array();
$result['thousand_low'] = floor($num / 1000) * 1000;
$result['thousand_high'] = $result['thousand_low'] + 999;
```

Comment: Instead of round() you should use floor() ;)

Answer (score 2):

Untested (edit: but should work ;) ):

```
$number = 165124;
$low    = floor($number / 1000) * 1000;
$high   = $low + 999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the round function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) - you can specify the precision so you can customise the magnitude of the rounding.

Comment: ``round`` unfortunately doesn’t give the floor.

Answer (score 0):

```
 array('thousand_low' => floor($int/1000)*1000, 
'thousand_high' => floor($int/1000)*1000+999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used php in quite a while but i think it should look something like this :

```
$num_input = 165124;
$array['thousand_low'] = floor($num_input /  1000) * 1000;
$array['thousand_high'] = $array['thousand_low'] + 999;
```